# What is the difference in behaviour between props.children and a regular prop?

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference (if any) in the way React handles 'props.children' versus if I were simply to add the same JSX in as a prop? Is this just simply for better presentation of code?

```
<Parent>
    <Child />
    <Child />
</Parent>
```

**vs.**

```
<Parent otherChildren={<><Child /><Child /></>} />
```

Comment: I'd say it's equivalent to `<Parent otherChildren={[<Child />, <Child />]} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that props.children can be declared both in props and enclosed in JSX tag of the component.
Beside that, the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: Proof: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L205